# Geometric Sequences: What is $r^n$, and how do I find $r$?

Tags: calculus, summation, telescopic-series

I've been tasked to find the summation
$$\sum_{x=1}^{100} \frac{1}{x(x+1)}$$
without manually summing each term. I've looked at all the shortcuts I can find online, and I was only able to find shortcuts for constant multiples, squared terms, addition/subtraction, and the like.

I finally found something about [geometric sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula), but I'm having trouble understanding it. How do I find $r^n$ and $r$?

I tried to write out the first few terms. I got $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{6}$, $\frac{1}{12}$, and $\frac{1}{20}$. I can't really see a common ratio other than the formula itself. Maybe this isn't a geometric series? If not, how can I find this summation formulaically?

Comment: ***Hint:*** $\dfrac{1}{x(x+1)}=\dfrac{A}{x}+\dfrac{B}{x+1}$. Try and find $A$ and $B$ which would easily give you the solution.

Comment: This is a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20telescoping%20series,For%20example%2C%20the%20series)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a geometric series. One way of solving it is to write$$\sum_{x=1}^{100} \frac{1}{x(x+1)} = \sum_{x=1}^{100} \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{101} = \frac{100}{101}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum _{x=1}^{100} \frac{1}{x(x+1)}=\\\sum _{x=1}^{100} \left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{98}-\frac{1}{99}+\frac{1}{99}-\frac{1}{100}+\frac1{100}-\frac1{101}=\\
1-\frac{1}{101}=\frac{100}{101}$$

Comment: Not sure what this answer adds to the one from The Solver Doe, except completely giving everything away.

Comment: @gt6989b "The Solver Doe" : I like this name !

Comment: @gt6989b Maybe OP did not know how telescoping works. Maybe I answered without knowing what the other user was doing. Maybe downvoting for so little can be quite rude...

Comment: @Raffaele (Maybe #1) After the other answer, I would expect the OP to do at least something for his problem, this would it - to figure out how exactly telescoping works. (Maybe #2) That is possible, but you published about 5 mins after his answer, and should have seen his on publishing. Either way, I would have downvoted for giving away the problem without any work on the OP side. (Maybe #3) I was not the only one to downvote, and not the first one either. Also note the upvote on my first comment after your post. I do not want to seem rude, so I will take away the downvote now.

Comment: @gt6989b  Sincerely, I am a user since 2013, but I never understood the reason why you and other users on MSE criticize "giving away" the solution. If OP asked is because they did not know the answer. Giving the answer is a must, in my opinion.

Comment: @Raffaele this is a hot topic here, very happy to have the conversation. Not sure where would be better -- let me know if you would like to have my private contact info, so we can connect.